# OpenGL DSA code not working while non-DSA works

Tags: c++, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-4

Here is the working code:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);

auto vertexCount = _vertices.size();
auto vertexSize = sizeof(Vertex);

auto totalSize = vertexCount * vertexSize;

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalSize, _vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize, (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize, (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);

glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize, (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);

glVertexAttribPointer(7, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize, (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(7);

glVertexAttribIPointer(8, 1, GL_SHORT, vertexSize, (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, texIndex));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(8);

if (_indices.size() > 0) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &_ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), _indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And here is the DSA version which oddly, doesn't work.

```
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &_vao);

auto vertexCount = _vertices.size();
auto vertexSize = sizeof(Vertex);

auto totalSize = vertexCount * vertexSize;

glCreateBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glNamedBufferData(_vbo, totalSize, _vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(_vao, 0, _vbo, 0, vertexSize);

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_vao, 4);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_vao, 5);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_vao, 6);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_vao, 7);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(_vao, 8);

glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_vao, 4, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_vao, 5, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_vao, 6, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_vao, 7, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(_vao, 8, 0);

glVertexArrayAttribFormat(_vao, 4, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Vertex, position));
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(_vao, 5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Vertex, normal));
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(_vao, 6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Vertex, color));
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(_vao, 7, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Vertex, uv));
glVertexArrayAttribIFormat(_vao, 8, 1, GL_SHORT, offsetof(Vertex, texIndex));

if (_indices.size() > 0) {
    glCreateBuffers(1, &_ebo);
    glNamedBufferData(_ebo, _indices.size() * sizeof(_indices[0]), _indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexArrayElementBuffer(_vao, _ebo);
}
```

Replacing the first code with the second one makes the rendering not produce any output. No error messages reported by `KHR_debug` and `glGetError` always return 0.

Comment: Changing the binding index from 0 to 5 makes the DSA version work, even more confusing. I don't do any binding to 0 besides here.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, I am instancing my geometry. I was doing

```
VBO vbo;
glCreateBuffers(1, &vbo);
glNamedBufferData(vbo, defaultSize * m4s, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

for (auto& mesh : model.lock()->_meshes) {
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(mesh._vao, 1, vbo, 0, m4s);

    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(mesh._vao, 0);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(mesh._vao, 1);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(mesh._vao, 2);
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(mesh._vao, 3);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(mesh._vao, 0, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(mesh._vao, 1, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(mesh._vao, 2, 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(mesh._vao, 3, 1);

    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(mesh._vao, 0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, v4s * 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(mesh._vao, 1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, v4s * 1);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(mesh._vao, 2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, v4s * 2);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(mesh._vao, 3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, v4s * 3);

    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(mesh._vao, 0, 1);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(mesh._vao, 1, 1);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(mesh._vao, 2, 1);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(mesh._vao, 3, 1);
}
```

See the last 4 gl calls? That is where the problem was. I thought the second parameter was a vertex attrib index (2. param to glEnableVertexArrayAttrib), while in reality it was the buffer binding index (2. param to glVertexArrayVertexBuffer). Deleting the lines with 0, 2 and 3 fixed the problem.